# how to startup Eclipse REST project so I can debug it

Tags: java, eclipse, rest, debugging, wildfly

I have two eclipse java projects:

- backend REST services supposed to be run on WildFly service container.
- frontend - javaFx app.

How to properly run above application so I can debug code existing in backend.

I can eassily start frontende by run click -> Debug As -> Java App

- it starts succesfully but then I got following error:

*Invalid response status. Expected 200 received 404*

I tried different ways:

- run WildFly 9.x from Servers

Eventually without success.

Comment: Generate a WAR and then deploy to WildFly locally outside of Eclipse?

404 means it's not deployed the service properly, or it doesn't exist at the URL you think it does.

Comment: It allowed me to deploy app with success, but then again I cannot debug it

Answer (score 0):

Start the Server in debug mode , in eclipse there is option to start the server in debug mode.
Then set the breakpoint then you will able to debug you code

Answer (score 0):

Of course if you run only your JavaFX app, by click on Run As->Java App, you will get 404 - Not found response status, as the backed REST service is not running.

So to be able to debug your backend (rest service) start your web service in one of servlet containers with debug option: -Xdebug -Xrunjdwp:server=y,transport=dt_socket,address=5213,suspend=n

and then on eclipse create remote debug configuration and connect to that 5213 port.

And to make a request to backend service, you can do it by one of REST client, or run your JavaFX app and make request.